# Detect online/store Square Payments

Tags: square-connect

On the /payments endpoint, is there a way to know for sure that a payment has been made online and not in a physical store?

I cannot find something about this in this endpoint https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntryMethod field provides the method with which a form of tender was entered.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#enum-tenderentrymethod